# Suspend execution of AJAX callback after multiple AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have 2 Ajax calls in my script, Each one of them has a different callback to execute on call success.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "url1",
    success: foo1
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "url2",
    success: foo2
});
```

I have another function, `Clear()` , that i would like to activate once all the ajax calls returned, but I do not want that the callbacks (`foo1` and `foo2`) will be executed until I execute `Clear()`.

I have searched for an answer but did not found clear one. What can |I do to solve this? is there any flag or function that deals in those kind of problems?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it okay for if you do the ajax call  #1 and when this success call the ajax #2?

Comment: Yes, the order of execution of `foo1()` and `foo2()` is not important. The important thing is that `Clear()` will be called **before** their execution.

Comment: You're looking for `$.when`, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I agree with any of these existing solutions, as JQuery gives us a tool for just this purpose: `$.when`

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

When using `$.when`, JQuery aggregates all the promises into a single promise, and only resolves when *all* promises have resolved. If *any* promises are rejected, the `fail` is called.

```
const promise1 = $.Deferred();
const promise2 = $.Deferred();

promise1.resolve({data: 'Promise 1'});
promise2.resolve({data: 'Promise 2'});

$.when.apply(this, [promise1, promise2])
  .done((promise1Data, promise2Data) => {
      // All of our promises have resolved
      // And we have all our data from each promise
      // Do the work of clear() here
      console.log(promise1Data.data)
      console.log(promise2Data.data)
  })
  .fail((error) => {         
      console.error('One or more promises failed')
  });
```

As we can see, in the context of this question, you can do whatever logic is necessary inside of the `done` of the `$.when`. If you reach this point, you're guaranteed that all promises have resolved.

The above code block outputs the following to console

```
> "Promise 1"
> "Promise 2"
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/MyrJYB?editors=0011

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement a naive but easy solution as below, or otherwise take a look at [JS Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) if you need a stronger solution.

```
var foo1Data, foo2Data;
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "url1",
  success: function(data) {
    if (foo2Data) {
       Clear();
       foo1(data);
       foo2(foo2Data);
    }
    else {
      foo1Data = data;
    }
  }
});

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "url2",
  success: function(data) {
    if (foo1Data) {
       Clear();
       foo1(foo1Data);
       foo2(data);
    }
    else {
      foo2Data = data;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If the AJAX calls return data, then the `else` statements would also need to store that returned data in an external variable for the other one to use.

Comment: I'm not sure what `Clear()` does, but the OP probably wants it to run *before* the calls to `foo`. Or maybe this solution even removes the need for `Clear()`.

Comment: @4castle is right, I have different data to `foo1()` and `foo2` that comes from Ajax response... I can't execute them in the same scope.

Answer (score -1):

Untested, but you could try something like this using `when`.

```
// each object in responses contains the response text,
// status, and jqXHR object for each ajax call
function clear(responses) {
  // do something
  foo1(responses[0]);
  foo2(responses[1]);
};

$.when(ajax1, ajax2).done(clear);
```

Comment: Ok, worth a try... how can I access the data in respones[0], for example?

Comment: `responses[0].responseText` I think.